# Calculating sum,count of multiple top K values spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have an input dataframe of the format

```
+---------------------------------+
|name| values |score    |row_number|
+---------------------------------+
|A    |1000   |0        |1        |
|B    |947    |0        |2        |
|C    |923    |1        |3        |
|D    |900    |2        |4        |
|E    |850    |3        |5        |
|F    |800    |1        |6        |
+---------------------------------+
```

I need to get sum(values) when score > 0 and row_number < K (i,e) SUM of all values when score > 0 for the top k values in the dataframe.

I am able to achieve this by running the following query for top 100 values

```
val top_100_data = df.select(
      count(when(col("score") > 0 and col("row_number")<=100, col("values"))).alias("count_100"),
      sum(when(col("score") > 0 and col("row_number")<=100, col("values"))).alias("sum_filtered_100"),
      sum(when(col("row_number") <=100, col(values))).alias("total_sum_100")
    )
```

However, I need to fetch data for top 100,200,300......2500. meaning I would need to run this query 25 times and finally union 25 dataframes.

I'm new to spark and still figuring lots of things out. What would be the best approach to solve this problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `Array` of limits as

```
val topFilters = Array(100, 200, 300) // you can add more
```

Then you can loop through the `topFilters` array and create the `dataframe` you require. **I suggest you to use `join` rather than `union` as `join` will give you separate `columns` and `unions` will give you separate `rows`. You can do the following**

Given your `dataframe` as

```
+----+------+-----+----------+
|name|values|score|row_number|
+----+------+-----+----------+
|A   |1000  |0    |1         |
|B   |947   |0    |2         |
|C   |923   |1    |3         |
|D   |900   |2    |200       |
|E   |850   |3    |150       |
|F   |800   |1    |250       |
+----+------+-----+----------+
```

You can do by using the `topFilters` array defined above as

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
var finalDF : DataFrame = Seq("1").toDF("rowNum")
for(k <- topFilters) {
  val top_100_data = df.select(lit("1").as("rowNum"), sum(when(col("score") > 0 && col("row_number") < k, col("values"))).alias(s"total_sum_$k"))
  finalDF = finalDF.join(top_100_data, Seq("rowNum"))
}
finalDF.show(false)
```

Which should give you final `dataframe` as

```
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|rowNum|total_sum_100|total_sum_200|total_sum_300|
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|1     |923          |1773         |3473         |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

You can do the same for your 25 limits that you have.

If you intend to use `union`, then the idea is similar to above.

I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

If you require union then you can apply following logic with the same limit array defined above

```
var finalDF : DataFrame = Seq((0, 0, 0, 0)).toDF("limit", "count", "sum_filtered", "total_sum")
for(k <- topFilters) {
  val top_100_data = df.select(lit(k).as("limit"), count(when(col("score") > 0 and col("row_number")<=k, col("values"))).alias("count"),
    sum(when(col("score") > 0 and col("row_number")<=k, col("values"))).alias("sum_filtered"),
    sum(when(col("row_number") <=k, col("values"))).alias("total_sum"))
  finalDF = finalDF.union(top_100_data)
}
finalDF.filter(col("limit") =!= 0).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-----+-----+------------+---------+
|limit|count|sum_filtered|total_sum|
+-----+-----+------------+---------+
|100  |1    |923         |2870     |
|200  |3    |2673        |4620     |
|300  |4    |3473        |5420     |
+-----+-----+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, This was very helpful!!. So I would be needing 3 columns for every K (sum_100_filtered_score, total_sum_100,count_filtered_score_100). By joining the dataset I get one column for each field. Which is why i'm trying to use union

Comment: see my updated answer :) You can accept and upvote if it really helped you